# How does python know a function argument is the column in a df?

Tags: python, function

If a function is defined and there are a number of parameters, how is it recognised what those parameters are? For example:

```
def count_entries(df, col_name='A'):
    
    # Extract column from DataFrame: col
    col = df[A]
    
    # Iterate over the column in DataFrame
    for entry in col:
    # If entry is in cols_count, add 1
        if entry in cols_count.keys():
            cols_count[entry] += 1

        # Else add the entry to cols_count, set the value to 1
        else:
            cols_count[entry] = 1

    # Return the cols_count dictionary
    return cols_count
```

How does python understand that col_name='A' is referring to a column within a df? Is it due to the prior argument being a df, so python knows that the next argument will be a column? Is this a default setting? Suppose, we didn't actually want to access a column in this parameter, instead we wanted to pass something else, would this parameter still default to a column? Or alternatively, in the function header, the parameter

```
col_name='A'
```

is only understood by python due to subsequent code when we define col as:

```
col=df[A]
```

and it's the use of the square brackets after a dataframe that enables python to recognise it as a column and prior to this it is not understood that I want to access columns in the df?

Comment: `df[A]` should be `df[col_name]`. It knows that it's a column name because that's how indexing of dataframes works.

Comment: Just like `list_name[n]` knows that `n` is an index, and `dict_name[x]` knows that `x` is a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume your code has a typo and `col = df[A]` was supposed to be `col = df[col_name]`. If not, there's some other deep magic happening that needs to be clarified.*

---

The short answer is that Python doesn't know that, and the concept of "column name" only appears when you do `df[col_name]`.

The long answer is that all values in Python, be they arguments or local variables, only care about themselves. In some cases you might see type annotations:

```
col_name: str = 'A'
```

Which tells type-checking tools that `col_name` is supposed to be a string. But there's no type "column name", what happens instead is that the dataframe will have a method with the special name `__getitem__` that accepts string values. You can make your own like so:

```
class MyClass:
    def __getitem__(self, index: str):
        # You're allowed to do anything here.
        # Let's reverse the "index" and return it.
        return ''.join(reversed(index))
    
name: str = 'example'
obj = MyClass()
print(obj[name]) # 'elpmaxe'
```

Note that the only relation between the local variable `name` and the function argument `index` is that they have compatible types (both `str`).